# MySQL SELECT query not selecting exact match?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id_product, t.id_tag, t.name FROM ps_tag t 
JOIN ps_product p ON p.id_product=t.name AND t.name 
IN(SELECT id_product FROM ps_product) 
AND p.available_for_order = 1 
GROUP BY t.id_tag, p.id_product
ORDER BY `p`.`id_product`  DESC
```

This query returns results like this (among the correct ones)

```
id_product  id_tag  name    
43         79020    43P109
43         79021    43P109
43         79022    43P109
43         105796   43
43         114789   43
```

The `ON` statement says `p.id_product=t.name`, but 43 is not 43P109. Where did I go wrong here? I need only the results where `p.id_product` equals exactly `t.name`, so only the name 43 will be returned?

Comment: Does the query return anything different if you remove the "AND t.NAME IN( SELECT id_product FROM ps_product)" clause in the JOIN?

Comment: @Forty3
no, it is the same. I added it in hope to resolve it, but it is same both ways.

Comment: I think the Mysql docs referred to by @weirdan seem to provide the answer:

"The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'."

Looks like it is converting '43' to a numeric in the equality test. Very disconcerting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is casting problem integer vs char

try using

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.id_product, t.id_tag, t.name 
 FROM ps_tag t 
 JOIN ps_product p ON CAST(p.id_product as char(50)) =t.name 
     AND t.name IN(SELECT id_product 
        FROM ps_product)
     AND p.available_for_order = 1 
 GROUP BY t.id_tag, p.id_product
 ORDER BY `p`.`id_product`  DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

`42` is actually equal to `"42Pwhatever"`, as far as mysql is concerned:

```
mysql> select 42 = "42P123";
+---------------+
| 42 = "42P123" |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Cast your integer column as binary string if you want this comparison to fail:

```
mysql> select cast(42 as binary) = "42P123";
+-------------------------------+
| cast(42 as binary) = "42P123" |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The reason for this is that your columns have different types, and when that happens in an expression mysql tries to convert them to a common type (integer in you specific case). Thus `"42P123"` becomes `42` (it stops conversion on first non-digit character. Explicit cast above tells mysql to convert integer to string instead, and then compare strings.

See mysql conversion rules here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html